# Jupyter Kernel Never Starts

Tags: jupyter

New install of Jupyter on Ubuntu, updated kernel with pip.  No dice starting every single time.

I have no idea what's causing the problem. Ideas?  I did some searches and tried everything I came across.

```
 Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=485daf25567ae55ee8b142d9c86629393549b2c004ef5f06
[I 18:03:58.790 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=485daf25567ae55ee8b142d9c86629393549b2c004ef5f06 (127.0.0.1) 1.04ms
[I 18:04:02.282 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 709ff2ac-703f-40e0-9a6c-afca4492eedc
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[I 18:04:05.281 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[I 18:04:08.341 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[I 18:04:11.384 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[W 18:04:12.390 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 709ff2ac-703f-40e0-9a6c-afca4492eedc
[I 18:04:14.434 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 709ff2ac-703f-40e0-9a6c-afca4492eedc restarted
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[W 18:04:17.475 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 18:04:17.477 NotebookApp] Kernel 709ff2ac-703f-40e0-9a6c-afca4492eedc died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel 709ff2ac-703f-40e0-9a6c-afca4492eedc restarted failed!
[W 18:04:17.536 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 18:04:17.537 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/5174b016-ff67-4ddc-8390-a4ce76fbd4b8 (127.0.0.1) 2.71ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/codeSandbox.ipynb
[W 18:04:21.529 NotebookApp] Session not found: session_id='5174b016-ff67-4ddc-8390-a4ce76fbd4b8'
[W 18:04:21.529 NotebookApp] 404 DELETE /api/sessions/5174b016-ff67-4ddc-8390-a4ce76fbd4b8 (127.0.0.1) 1.80ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/codeSandbox.ipynb
[I 18:04:21.571 NotebookApp] Kernel started: e8ea730b-3780-4445-8429-4decff4ec502
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[I 18:04:24.570 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[I 18:04:27.614 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[I 18:04:30.667 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[W 18:04:31.608 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from e8ea730b-3780-4445-8429-4decff4ec502
[I 18:04:33.713 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel e8ea730b-3780-4445-8429-4decff4ec502 restarted
Invalid argument (bundled/zeromq/src/tcp_address.cpp:199)
[W 18:04:36.758 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 18:04:36.762 NotebookApp] Kernel e8ea730b-3780-4445-8429-4decff4ec502 died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel e8ea730b-3780-4445-8429-4decff4ec502 restarted failed!
[W 18:04:36.828 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 18:04:36.829 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/4095438e-66c7-4392-b116-77aa79b301da (127.0.0.1) 2.97ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/codeSandbox.ipynb
```

Comment: Which kernel are you using (I'm assuming ipython) and are you using a custom profile or startup script.  Are you able to start the jupyter console?